# How to add .dll file in CLI project without visual studio?

Tags: c#, .net-core, dotnet-cli

I deleted Visual Studio, but i love c#. I download dotnet from [dotnet official site](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/download/dotnet-core/current/runtime) and installed it. Then i writen in command line `dotnet new console` and all work, `dotnet run` work. Then i make other folder and there writen `dotnet new classlib` (is .dll) and it work. But i don't know how to add my .dll file into my project. How to do it?

Comment: "*I deleted Visual Studio*" - i have never heard of such sacrilege

Comment: I have not memory on disk C:/

Comment: @CodeCaster can you give me xml code for it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You either edit the XML of the .csproj file manually, or [do it on the command line](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-add-reference):

```
dotnet add app/app.csproj reference lib/lib.csproj
```

This adds the XML for you:

```
<ItemGroup>
  <ProjectReference Include="..\lib\lib.csproj" />
</ItemGroup>
```